# Again and Again prints the same value

Tags: java, methods, text-files

I have been asked to check the number of times a team's name is on the text that is on my computer. I wrote the code, the code works fine by counting the number of times the team name has appeared but it just keeps on asking the name of the team, like 50 times since the size of the array i declared is 50. Please help me out. Thanks.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class worldSeries 
{
    public String getName(String teamName)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(" Enter the Team Name : " );
        teamName = keyboard.nextLine();
        return teamName;
    }

    public int checkSeries1 () throws IOException
    {
        String teamName="";
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);


        String[] winners = new String[50];
        int  i = 0 ;
        File file = new File ("WorldSeriesWinners.txt");
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
        while ( inputFile.hasNext () && i < winners.length )
        {
            winners[i] = inputFile.nextLine(); 
            i++;
        }
        inputFile.close();

        int count = 0;
        for ( int  index = 0 ; index < winners.length ; index ++ )
        {
            if ( getName(teamName).equals(winners[index]))
            {
                count++;

            }
        }
        return count;

    }

    public static void main(String[]Args)
    {
        String teamName = "";
        worldSeries object1 = new worldSeries();

        try
        {
            System.out.println(" The Number of times " + object1.getName(teamName) + "won the Championship is : " +object1.checkSeries1());
        }
        catch ( IOException ioe )

        {
            System.out.println(" Exception!!! ");

            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `for getName(teamName)`... What did you expect?

Comment: @user3295442 I removed the "multithreading" tag.

Comment: ***Very*** similar question asked by a *different user* twenty minutes after this one was posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22120122/invoking-to-type-the-team-name-twice-instead-of-once

Answer (score 4):

Calling `getName()` once every loop will cause the program to ask for a team name every loop:

```
        int count = 0;
        for ( int  index = 0 ; index < winners.length ; index ++ )
        {
            if ( getName(teamName).equals(winners[index]))
            {
                count++;

            }
        }
```

By moving `getName()` out of the loop, it will only be called once (and a team name will only be requested once):

```
    int count = 0;
    String nameOfTeam = getName(teamName); // This line runs getName() once

    for ( int  index = 0 ; index < winners.length ; index ++ )
    {
        if ( nameOfTeam.equals(winners[index]))
        {
            count++;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't call 'GetName' in the loop, call it once before the loop and store the result.

Answer (score 1):

In the method `checkSeries1()` remove the method call for getName(teamName) out of for loop and call getName() only once outside for loop, like this:

```
int count = 0;
String name = getName(teamName);
for ( int  index = 0 ; index < winners.length ; index ++ )
{
    if ( name.equals(winners[index]))
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```