# Invoking to type the team name twice instead of once

Tags: java, methods, printing

I have been asked to check if the team name is present in the text file I had created on my computer. I have written the complete code but the output is always invoking me type the name of the team twice before counting the number of times the team's name is present in the file. Please do see this, and let me know. Thanks.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class worldSeries 
{
    public String getName(String teamName)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(" Enter the Team Name : " );
        teamName = keyboard.nextLine();
        return teamName;
    }

    public int checkSeries1 () throws IOException
    {
        String teamName="";


        String[] winners = new String[50];
        int  i = 0 ;
        File file = new File ("WorldSeriesWinners.txt");
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
        while ( inputFile.hasNext () && i < winners.length )
        {
            winners[i] = inputFile.nextLine(); 
            i++;
        }
        inputFile.close();

        int count = 0;
        String nameOfTeam = getName(teamName);

        for ( int  index = 0 ; index < winners.length ; index ++ )
        {
            if ( nameOfTeam.equals(winners[index]))
            {
                count++;

            }
        }
        return count;

    }

    public static void main(String[]Args)
    {
        String teamName = "";
        worldSeries object1 = new worldSeries();

        try
        {
            System.out.println(" The Number of times " + object1.getName(teamName) + "won the Championship is : " +object1.checkSeries1());
        }
        catch ( IOException ioe )

        {
            System.out.println(" Exception!!! ");

            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you posting a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22119883/again-and-again-prints-the-same-value) but under a [different name](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3339936/user3339936)??

Comment: Just put a breakpoint in the `getName()` method, and see when it is called, and use the call stack (or just stepping out of it) to see where it is called from.

Answer (score 1):

Count how many times you call `getTeamName()` -- you do it twice. And so you see it twice.

More importantly, the WorldSeries class should probably not have any Scanner objects or IO inside of it. Instead it should hold the WorldSeries information and have methods to check team names against the data. All user I/O should be done in your main method (in this program at least).

Comment: I am not doing it twice. I see it only once when I am assigning it to String nameOfTeam.

Comment: @user3369285: don't take my word on it, use your IDE to count the number of times you call it. Seriously. The method shouldn't take a parameter either.

Comment: My professor wants me to do it in the class and not in the main method

Comment: Again count them. The word processor or IDE won't lie. Just search getName in the file above.

Comment: I just did it with my word find option it said thrice. One when i am declaring the getName() class then when i am assigning newName and then when i am printing it in the main method

Answer (score 1):

Your code is doing this:

```
System.out.println(" The Number of times " + object1.getName(teamName) + "won the Championship is : " +object1.checkSeries1());
```

Your `getName` method is prompting for the name- it is being called directly in the line above, and it is also called indirectly (inside `checkSeries1` on the same line). So that means it's being called twice in that line...

You will want to reconsider where prompting is done and do some refactoring to fix it.

Comment: Can you tell me the change that i could do to make it better?

Comment: A starting point could be to put your prompting into a function called `promptForName`, and make `getName` much simpler? Then you can call `getName` as much as you want without it reprompting.

Comment: 1+ for good advice. @user3369285: you really need to do some thinking on your own here. Else you'll never learn how to code.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a way to do this in Java:

```
import java.io.*;

public class WorldSeries
{
    /**
     * Count the number of lines a string occurs on in a file.
     */
    public static final void main(String[] argv)
        throws IOException
    {
        if(argv.length<2)
        {
            showUsage();
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        int count=0;
        String term = argv[0];
        String filename = argv[1];

        LineNumberReader reader = new LineNumberReader(
            new FileReader(filename)
            );

        for(String line=reader.readLine(); line != null; line=reader.readLine())
        {
            if(line.indexOf(term) > -1)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(count);
    }

    private static final void showUsage()
    {
        System.out.println("Search for term in a file.");
        System.out.println("USAGE: <term> <file-name>");
    }
}
```

But you can also do this with scripting:

```
grep -c "Boston Red Sox" world-series.txt
```

Comment: If you're going to down-vote an answer which is correct in one reading of this question, it'd be nice if you provide an explanation for your down-vote.